# Assigning a string to a char value from a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, char, uint32-t

I'm trying to assign a string to a char value from a struct

```
typedef struct blah_param_s {
    struct blah_param_s*  param_next;
    blah_param_type_t     param_type;
} blah_param_t;

typedef struct blah_param_char_s {
    blah_param_t    param_hdr;
    char*           param_val;
} blah_param_char_t;
```

my function is:

```
static inline char blah_get_param_char (blah_param_t* param_p)
{
    return (((blah_param_char_t*)param_p)->param_val);
}
```

And the offending code that kicks this all off is:

```
((blah_param_char_t*)new_param_p)->param_val = value;
```

where value is "blah"

Which give me a warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast

Now for integers it works:

```
typedef struct blah_param_int_s {
    blah_param_t    param_hdr;
    uint32_t        param_val;
} blah_param_int_t;

static inline uint32_t blah_get_param_int (blah_param_t* param_p)
{
    return (((blah_param_int_t*)param_p)->param_val);
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: If `param_val` is of type `char *` so should be your return type.  A `char` and a `char *` is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return the first character of the string from the function `blah_get_param_char` then use `*(((blah_param_int_t*)param_p)->param_val)`
instead of `(((blah_param_char_t*)param_p)->param_val);`

Or, if you want to return the entire string then return as pointer ( `char*` ) to the string.